# Ошибка: неопределённая ссылка на функцию (gcc, cmake) (срочно нужно!)

Tags: linux, c, gcc, cmake

На начальном локальном репозитории всё нормально работало. На гитхабе сборка упала.  При клонировании репозитория в другую папку сначала происходит дамп памяти, когда редактирую код возникают ошибки "неопределённая ссылка на функцию", иногда когда редактирую начинает работать нормально, но после загрузки в гитхаб всё начинается заново. Файлы зависимостей почти одинаковые, даже после изменения их вручную ничего не меняется.
Репозиторий:
https://github.com/MGsand/Beta-kurs

```
 $ make 
Makefile:63: предупреждение: переопределение способа для цели «run»
Makefile:17: предупреждение: старый способ для цели «run» игнорируются
./bin/format
Enter filename
a.txt
Open file
make: *** [Makefile:63: run] Исключение в операции с плавающей точкой (сделан дамп памяти)
```

Мейк тест:

```
$ make test
Makefile:63: предупреждение: переопределение способа для цели «run»
Makefile:17: предупреждение: старый способ для цели «run» игнорируются
gcc -I thirdparty -I src/lib -MMD -c -o obj/ctests/test_1.o ctests/test_1.c
gcc -I thirdparty -I src/lib -MMD -c -o obj/ctests/main.o ctests/main.c
gcc -I thirdparty -I src/lib -MMD -o bin/main_test obj/ctests/test_1.o obj/ctests/main.o obj/src/lib/lib.a
/usr/bin/ld: obj/ctests/test_1.o: в функции «ctest_functions_noformat_test_run»:
test_1.c:(.text+0x754): неопределённая ссылка на «noformat»
/usr/bin/ld: test_1.c:(.text+0x7ec): неопределённая ссылка на «noformat»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:54: bin/main_test] Ошибка 1
```

Изменение кода

```
$ make
Makefile:63: предупреждение: переопределение способа для цели «run»
Makefile:17: предупреждение: старый способ для цели «run» игнорируются
gcc -I src/lib -o bin/format obj/src/format/kursovikkk.o obj/src/lib/lib.a
/usr/bin/ld: obj/src/format/kursovikkk.o: в функции «main»:
kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x12): неопределённая ссылка на «Cleanabz»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x2a): неопределённая ссылка на «selectfail»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x34): неопределённая ссылка на «nof»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x3e): неопределённая ссылка на «save»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x113): неопределённая ссылка на «selectfail»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x11f): неопределённая ссылка на «Clean»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x12b): неопределённая ссылка на «strlong»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x138): неопределённая ссылка на «fo»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x144): неопределённая ссылка на «Cleanabz»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x14e): неопределённая ссылка на «fo»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x15a): неопределённая ссылка на «fo»
/usr/bin/ld: kursovikkk.c:(.text+0x166): неопределённая ссылка на «paragraph»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:40: bin/format] Ошибка 1
```

мейкфайл:

```
APP_NAME = format
LIB_NAME = lib
TEST_NAME = main_test

TESTFLAGS = -I thirdparty
CFLAGS = -I src/lib
DEPSFLAGS = -MMD
CC = gcc

BIN_DIR = bin
OBJ_DIR = obj
SRC_DIR = src
TEST_DIR = ctests

# RUN
run: all
    $(APP_PATH) $(BIN_DIR)

APP_PATH = $(BIN_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
LIB_PATH = $(OBJ_DIR)/$(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)/$(LIB_NAME).a
TEST_PATH = $(BIN_DIR)/$(TEST_NAME)

APP_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)/*.c)
APP_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(APP_SOURCES))

LIB_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)/*.c)
LIB_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(LIB_SOURCES))

TEST_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(TEST_DIR)/*.c)
TEST_OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(TEST_SOURCES))

DEPS = $(APP_OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(LIB_OBJECTS:.o=.d)

all: $(APP_PATH)

-include $(DEPS)

# BUILD
$(APP_PATH): $(APP_OBJECTS) $(LIB_PATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

$(LIB_PATH): $(LIB_OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPSFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< 


# TEST
test: $(LIB_PATH) $(TEST_PATH)
    $(TEST_PATH)

$(TEST_PATH): $(TEST_OBJECTS) $(LIB_PATH)
    $(CC) $(TESTFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPSFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

$(OBJ_DIR)/ctests/main.o: ctests/main.c
    $(CC) $(TESTFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPSFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/ctests/test_1.o: ctests/test_1.c
    $(CC) $(TESTFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPSFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

run: $(APP_PATH)
    ./bin/format


# CLEAN
clean:
    $(RM) $(APP_PATH) $(TEST_PATH) $(OBJ_DIR)/*/*/*.[aod] $(OBJ_DIR)/test/*.[aod]
```

майн

```
#include "functions.h" 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    Cleanabz();
    char c;
    int ds = 40;
    int e = 0;
    selectfail();
    nof();
    save();
    while (1) {
        system("clear");
        puts("  ");
        puts("  ** Formatter **");
        puts("  ");
        puts("  1 - Select file");
        puts("  2 - Clean all file");
        puts("  3 - Change string length ");
        puts("  4 - No format");
        puts("  5 - Format ");
        puts("  6 - Paragraph ");
        puts("  0 - Exit");
        puts("  ");

        c = getchar();
        switch (c) {
        case '1':
            selectfail();
            break;
        case '2':
            Clean();
            break;
        case '3':
            ds = strlong();
            fo();
            break;
        case '4':
            Cleanabz();
            fo();
            break;
        case '5':
            fo();
            break;
        case '6':
            paragraph();
            break;
        case '0':
            e = ds;
            ds = e;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

заголовочный файл

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void format(char fname[255], int ds);

void noformat(char fname[255]);

void paragraph();

void selectfail();

void Clean();

void Cleanabz();

void save();

void printsave();

int strlong();

void nof();

void fo();

#endif
```

файл с функциями

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <string.h>

FILE* f;

int ds = 40;
int nstr = 0;

int r;
int n = 10, ij = 0;
char chaa;
char fname[255];

char cs[15];
int spper = 1;
int flag = 0;
int abz = -1;
int flp = 1;
int ksim;
char* p;
char abzz[2000];

void format(char fname[255], int ds)
{
    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    char cha;
    char pred;
    int k = 0, ks = 1;
    int stran = 1, ki = 0;
    if ((abz >= 0) && (abz <= ks))
        k += 3;

    do {
        cha = fgetc(f);
        k++;
        if ((k % ds) == 0)
            ks++;
    } while (cha != EOF);
    nstr = ks;
    ksim = k;
    rewind(f);
    printf("ds %d\n", ds);
    char mt[ks][ds];
    for (int i = 0; i < ks; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ds; j++) {
            if (((i == abz) || (abzz[i] == 1))
                && (j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2)) {
                cha = ' ';
                mt[i][j] = cha;
            } else {
                mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
                cha = mt[i][j];
                while (cha == '\n') {
                    mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
                    cha = mt[i][j];
                }
                while (pred == cha && cha == ' ') {
                    mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
                    cha = mt[i][j];
                }
                pred = cha;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen(fname, "w");
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen(fname, "r+");
    for (int i = 0; i < ks; i++) {
        ki++;
        for (int j = 0; j < ds; j++) {
            cha = mt[i][j];
            if (cha == EOF)
                continue;
            else
                fwrite(&cha, sizeof cha, 1, f);
        }
        fputs("\n", f);
        if (ki == 40) {
            fprintf(f, "\n         %d", stran);
            fputs("\n", f);
            stran++;
            ki = 0;
        }
        abz = -1;
    }
    if (ki != 0) {
        fputs("\n", f);
        fprintf(f, "         %d", stran);
    }

    fclose(f);
}

void noformat(char fname[255])
{
    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    char cha;
    char pred;
    int k = 0, ks = 1;

    do {
        cha = fgetc(f);
        k++;
        if ((k % ds) == 0)
            ks++;
    } while (cha != EOF);
    nstr = ks;
    ksim = k;
    rewind(f);
    char mt[ks][ds];
    for (int i = 0; i < ks; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ds; j++) {
            mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
            cha = mt[i][j];
            while (cha == '\n') {
                mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
                cha = mt[i][j];
            }
            while (pred == cha && cha == ' ') {
                mt[i][j] = fgetc(f);
                cha = mt[i][j];
            }
            pred = cha;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen(fname, "w");
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen(fname, "r+");
    for (int i = 0; i < ks; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ds; j++) {
            cha = mt[i][j];
            if (cha == EOF)
                continue;
            else
                fwrite(&cha, sizeof cha, 1, f);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void paragraph()
{
    int oi;

    puts("enter the line");
    scanf("%d", &oi);
    if (oi > 0 && oi <= nstr) {
        abz = oi - 1;
        abzz[abz] = 1;
        fo();
        flp = 0;
    } else {
        puts(" Error ");
    }
}

void Clean()
{
    f = fopen(fname, "w");
    fclose(f);
}

int strlong()
{
    int dst;
    puts(" Enter new string length \n  ");
    scanf("%d", &dst);
    if (dst > 0 && dst < 100) {
        ds = dst;
        fo();
    } else {
        puts(" Error ");
    }
    return dst;
}

void Cleanabz()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        abzz[i] = 0;
    }
}

void save()
{
    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    p = (char*)malloc(ksim * sizeof(char));
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ksim; i++) {
        p[i] = fgetc(f);
        chaa = p[i];
    }
    if (chaa == ' ')
        y++;
    fclose(f);
}

void printsave()
{
    f = fopen(fname, "w");
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen(fname, "r+");
    for (int i = 0; i < ksim; i++) {
        chaa = p[i];

        fwrite(&chaa, sizeof chaa, 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void selectfail()
{
    printf(" Enter filename \n");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    while ((f = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error open, file not faund \n ");
        printf(" Enter filename \n");
        scanf("%s", fname);
    }
    printf("Open file \n");
}

void nof()
{
    noformat(fname);
}

void fo()
{
    printsave();
    format(fname, ds);
}
```

Comment: Очень срочно, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что у вас происходит. Я склонировал репозиторий  https://github.com/MGsand/Beta-kurs, собралось нормально. make test не собрался, но там надо было поправить CFLAGS, добавить `-I src`. Но в чём ВАША проблема? Дайте ссылку на ВАШ репозиторий, с всеми изменениями в makefile и прочем. Как нам угадать, что вы сделали?